# Capture curl stderr and print stdout in php

Tags: php

I'm using curl & php and something's not working.

How can I capture STDERR and print it to STDOUT in php when running through a web server?

Thanks

Comment: are you using the built in PHP cURL functions or making a `system()` call to curl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (curl_errno($ch)) { echo curl_error($ch); }
```

Answer (score 0):

TRY with

`curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,FALSE);` and print the error
 `$result = curl_exec($curl);`
  by `print_r($result);`